# Wordpress function.php - show secondary menu on only home page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to create a wordpress function.php to show a secondary menu only on the home page.

I have tried if (!is_home()) but could not get it to work. I would appreciate some help. Below is what I am staring with. Thanks.

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme'),
    'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'theme' ),
 ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

For eg: in your function.php

```
    register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Navigation', 'mtheme' )
) );
```

To display in front page for example we need to display in header. Then, you will need to add like this:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'fallback_cb' => 'page_menu','depth' =>1 ) ); ?>
```

For showing in home page only then add

```
<?php is_page($page); ?>
```

like
for example;

```
<?php
if(is_page('home')){ ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'fallback_cb' => 'page_menu','depth' =>1 ) ); ?>
}
else
{
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to use the code you provided but could not get it to work. If you can, could you use entire code from my original post. I have it set-up to use the primary and secondary menus. Thanks a million.

Comment: Can you please check with this code. Also can you specify in the above code already mentioned earlier where its not working. Did you tried giving directly in header.php like mentioned?

Comment: Hi Rahul, I was able to get it working using a ($post->post_title == "Home")  method. Thanks for your willingness to help. I appreciate it very much. Best regards.

Comment: Oh great it worked.... also one clarification is that you are giving this condition in which page header or functions.php. did you try is_page() in header.php?

Comment: Hi, I used the a plugin to insert the conditional code if ($post->post_title == "Home") at the beginning of each page. If there another method you think it's more efficient, I would gladly try it but could not get your first code to work.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a few attempts, I got lucky and got it to work using the code.

Placed at the beginning of each page

```html
<nav>
    <?php
if ($post->post_title == "Home"){
        wp_nav_menu( array('container_class' => 'menu-secondary',
        'theme_location' => 'secondary') );
        }
    ?>
</nav>
```

Following in function.php

```html
register_nav_menus( array(
    'primary' => __( 'Primary Menu', 'theme'),
    'secondary' => __( 'Secondary Menu', 'theme' ),
 ) );
```